# How to create a one-hot-encoding for the intermediate class?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, encoding

Let's say I have 3 classes: `0, 1, 2`
One-hot-encoding an array of labels can be done via pandas as follows:

[image]

What I'm interested in, is how to get an encoding that can handle an intermediate class, e.g. class in the middle between 2 classes.
For example:

- for class `0.4`, resulting encoding should be `[0.4, 0.6, 0]`
- for class `1.8`, resulting encoding should be `[0, 0.2, 0.8]`

Does anybody know such an encoder?
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Are you sure, this encoding occurs with`scikit-learn`?

Comment: there is no such encoder in `scikit-learn` as far as I know

Comment: Exactly, Do you want any solution?

Comment: This encoding has counterintuitive/illogical properties. For instance, 0.00001 should be [0.00001, 0.99999, 0], which we can round to [0, 1, 0]. Does it make sense?

Comment: It does if you have a multi-class classification problem, and you have high frequency time-series data that you want to resample by averaging)
Including these “average” classes would have regularizing effect like Mix-Up augmentation, but it needs to be encoded like this first in order to calculate cross-entropy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function for your strange encoding like the below:

```
import numpy as np
import math

def strange_encode(num, cnt_lbl):
    encode_arr = np.zeros(cnt_lbl)
    lbl = math.floor(num)
    if lbl != num:
        num -= lbl
        if num >= 0.5:
            encode_arr[lbl:lbl+2] = [1-num, num]
        else:
            encode_arr[lbl:lbl+2] = [num, 1-num]
    else:
        encode_arr[lbl] = 1
    return encode_arr
```

Output:

```
>>> encode(0.0, cnt_lbl=3)
array([1., 0., 0.])

>>> encode(2.0, cnt_lbl=3)
array([0., 0., 1.])

>>> encode(0.4, cnt_lbl=3)
array([0.4, 0.6, 0. ])

>>> encode(1.8, cnt_lbl=3)
array([0. , 0.2, 0.8])

# You can change the count of classes
>>> encode(2.5, cnt_lbl=4)
array([0. , 0. , 0.5, 0.5])

>>> encode(1.6, cnt_lbl=4)
array([0. , 0.4, 0.6, 0. ])

>>> encode(2, cnt_lbl=4)
array([0., 0., 1., 0.])
```

We can write a function for generating a dataframe for encoding like below:

```
import pandas as pd
def generate_df_encoding(arr_nums, num_classes):
    arr = np.zeros((len(arr_nums), num_classes))
    for idx, num in enumerate(arr_nums):
        arr[idx] = strange_encode(num, cnt_lbl=num_classes)
    return pd.DataFrame(arr)
```

Output:

```
>>> generate_df_encoding([0,0,1,2,0.4,1.8], num_classes=3)

    0    1      2
0   1.0  0.0    0.0
1   1.0  0.0    0.0
2   0.0  1.0    0.0
3   0.0  0.0    1.0
4   0.4  0.6    0.0
5   0.0  0.2    0.8
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this helps.

When you have categorial variables (classes), without order, that need to be encoded, you can use `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder()`. If there's an order, try using `sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder()`.

When you have numeric variables, the preprocessing steps I would use would be one of the many preprocessing tools you can find at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing ; a couple widely used are `MinMaxScaler()`, `RobustScaler()`, `StandardScaler()`, but it's best you read the API Reference guide to better understand when to use one or the other.